# Grouping and selecting symbology category data on ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, symbology, classification, arcgis-10.6

[image]

I have data and I categorized this data in symbology (ArcGIS 10.6.1). There is so many categories because of so many attribute table text.

How do I select just color parts on legend and how can I auto-group this data?

For example; 01:10; 2 - 01:10; 3 - 01:10; 5 => 01:10; 2-3-5.

Comment: Consider building new field(s) using the field calculator and/or python.

Comment: Start by looking up/playing with Symbology by Quantities. You will probably want to use graduated colors; also look at the options under the Classify button to group data.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to convert the text to numbers, and have only one value for each entry. You can do this in the Attribute Table - Add Field - Number Format: Numeric. Then Calculate Field.

Then right click on the layer to Symbology - Graduated Colors or perhaps Graduated Symbols. Graduated Colors can display colors only for numerical fields, not text fields.

https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/2.8/help/mapping/layer-properties/graduated-colors.htm

If you already know the values you want to show, you can choose the Number of Classes, and then Manual Break to edit those values. Otherwise, there are different options like Natural Breaks (Jenks), Quantile, Equal / Defined / Geometric, or Standard Deviation.

https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/2.8/help/mapping/layer-properties/data-classification-methods.htm

Below is the Symbology section from a sample tree file I have:

[image: Symbology Example]

Comment: your answer is for ArcGIS Pro while the question state ArcGis 10.6 (but the same principle apply to both software so it doesn't really matter)

Answer (score 0):

I assume you've already applied symbology to your data. Firstly just group all non coloured categories into one category (as shown in picture). Once you do this you can easily take out non coloured part out of legends by right clicking the legend.[image]